# I do not understand why I can not add object.getter() to MultivaluedMap

Tags: java, jersey-client, multivalue

I tried to send POST request with some parameters. For this I form `MultivaluedMap`

if I make this adding to `MultivaluedMap`

```
String ban = subscriber.getBan();
String username = user.getUsername();
postData.add("agent", username);
postData.add("datasource", "online");
postData.add("accountId", ban);
String json = RESTUtil.doPost(url, postData);
```

All work fine

but if I make this

```
postData.add("agent", user.getUsername());
postData.add("datasource", "online");
postData.add("accountId", subscriber.getBan());
String json = RESTUtil.doPost(url, postData);
```

I have error:

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List

It is my post method

```
public static String doPost(String url, MultivaluedMap formData) {
        try {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource wr = client.resource(url);
            client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            client.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            ClientResponse response2 = wr
                    .accept("application/json;")
                    .type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
            if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response2.getStatus());
            }
            return response2.getEntity(String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "callRestUrl:", e);
            JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
            jo.addProperty("resultCode", "EXCEPTION");
            jo.addProperty("details", e.getMessage());
            return GSON.toJson(jo);
        }
    }
```

And in second case I get error after .post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

I do not understand what is wrong. `subscriber.getBan()` and `user.getUsername()` return String like `ban` and `username`,  but if I use the getter, a have error.

And part 2. I found this article [this article](http://generationpalindrome.blogspot.com/2012/06/comsunjerseyapiclientclienthandlerexcep.html)

but I do not understand when to use `add` or `put` and their difference?

Comment: maybe because it is thrown by `subscriber#getBan()`, not by `add()`?

Comment: the difference is that `put()` replaces any existing value(s) while `add()` adds a new one

Answer (score 0):

Can you explicit how you create your instance of `MultivaluedMap`? How are you using it?

MultivaluedMap is a couple of key (single value) and value (list of objects). See the declaration:

```
public interface MultivaluedMap<K,V> extends Map<K,List<V>>
```

I suppose both of your snippets are used sequentially in the same piece of code. I the first case, you initialise the value for the key 'ban' (that's mean: the value is a list of one element), in the second case, you add a value to the list to the same key 'ban'. It happens exactly the same for the key 'username'. 
I your first case, Java automatically catch the list (of one value) to a string, after the second `add`, this cannot be the case.

To verify it, you can simply change the order (do first your second case, then the first one). You should get the same error, after the second.

To resolve your case, consider using the method `putSingle` instead of add if you want to "update/replace" the value, or re-initiate your instance of `formData` (formData = new ...) before using it another time.